# Dynamic View not displayed

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to take a quiz and if you answer a question wrong you see that question get added to a list of wrong questions.

Questions can be used in multiple quizes so I can't hard code ask question_1 then question_2 etc.

When I load the page I see the first question but then if I submit or refresh I see the right.html template. It doesn't ask all of the questions.

It should ask all of the questions before rendering the right.html page

```
for question in quiz.questions.all():
   if question not in asked_questions:
        asked_questions.append(question)
        return answer_question(request, quiz_id, question.id, module_list)
```

## models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice

#create a multiple choice quiz to start
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
asked_questions = []
module_list = []
module_list.append('test')

def take_quiz(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=str(quiz_id))

    for question in quiz.questions.all():
        if question not in asked_questions:
            asked_questions.append(question)
            return answer_question(request, quiz_id, question.id, module_list)
    #quiz is over
    return render (request, 'right.html')

def answer_question(request, quiz_id, question_id, module_list):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
    #module_list = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        choices = [(i, i) for i in question.choices.all()]
        form.fields['selection'].choices = choices

        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['selection'] != str(question.answer):
                module_list.append(question.module)
            return take_quiz(request, quiz_id)
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        choices = [(i, i) for i in question.choices.all()]
        form.fields['selection'].choices = choices

    return render(request, 'answer_question.html', {'question':question, 'form':form, 'module_list':module_list})
```

Comment: Can you please share right.html contents?

Comment: It contains "right" just so I know I am done the quiz

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on hosting this and making it available on the web, you should really start over. You shouldn't use lists like that to store stuff, you should use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) or the [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) instead. Also, you would be better off using a [FormWizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) for the quiz since it is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do: handle multiple forms and process them.

Comment: I am looking at FormWizard and I am wondering. How do you set the choices for a form field? How do you use the same form multiple but dynamic times. Apparently you can't use ajax with FormWizard is this still the case?

Comment: @Siecje So FormWizard has some methods that you can override to set things like that. You will probably want the [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form) method. As for using the same form multiple times, you can probably just dynamically create a list containing copies of the form to pass to the view. I'm not sure about the ajax, you can probably make a template that would use ajax, I can't think of anything that would prevent you from doing it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('answer_question', args=[quiz_id, question_id, module_list]))
```

to redirect your view to another view.

p.s.: reverse should contain the name of your 'answer_question' view

Comment: And I agree with Ngenator in the sessions or cache.

Comment: Reverse for 'answer_question' with arguments '(u'1', 1, ['test'])' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Like I said, the 'answer_question' should be replaced with the name that u have in your urls.py that leads to this view.

Comment: example in the urls.py: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^answer_question/$', 'app.views.view', name='answer_question'),
    )